# How can I integrate "MODE_PRIVATE" option in a Java FileWriter?

Tags: java, android

While creating an Android app, I'm trying to write a file within the phone's internal storage. Since the data is only text my preference is to use a Java FileWriter. However, I want only my app to make changes to it. If I use MODE_PRIVATE as an argument while creating a FileWriter as so

> `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("someFileName", MODE_PRIVATE)`

it throws an error saying

> Cannot resolve Constructor FileWriter(String, int)

If I use a FileOutputStream it works. Does the FileWriter not support such arguments? If not than are there any alternatives other than A FileOutputStream

Comment: "If I use a FileOutputStream it works" -- not really, as there is no constructor on [`FileOutputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream) that takes an `int`.

Comment: I don't think it works with a `java.io.FileOutputStream` but you can declare a `Writer` on an `OutputStream` using an `OutputStreamWriter`.

Comment: @CommonsWare using fos = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE) allows the functionality to be achieved